# function is async but getting error that await keyword cannot be used

Tags: javascript

The code below is causing the following console error: *Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function.*

```
async getData() {
    // an await occurs here for something else
                
    const menu = {
        'pounds': 'DemandModification',
        'combination': 'DemandCombinationOverride'
    };

    const overridesWithStaleBuckets = {};

    Object.entries(menu).forEach(o => {
        const overrideType = o[0];
        const api = o[1];

        const overrides = await this.$http.execute('read', api);
        overridesWithStaleBuckets[overrideType] = overridesWithStaleBuckets[overrideType] || {};
        overridesWithStaleBuckets[overrideType] = overrides;
    
    });

    // non problematic logic omitted

    return overridesWithStaleBuckets;
}
```

The console specifically calls out the `await` in this line as being the issue:

```
const overrides = await this.$http.execute('read', api);
```

Why is this error occurring when the function is async?

Comment: Your await appears inside the forEach callback.. Which is not async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use await in a `forEach` loop, you will need a normal for loop for this.

```js
let entries = Object.entries(menu);
for (let entry of entries) {
  //Do things
}
```